# Create Scheduled Tasks under Plesk with php

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I'm moving from a webserver with CPanel to one with Plesk. Under Cpanel, it's fairly simple to create and remove cronjobs with php:

```
<?php
// Create cron
$new_cron = "30 * * * * cd /home/account/public_html/; /usr/local/bin/php -f controller.php ".$argument1.PHP_EOL;
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
file_put_contents('/tmp/crontab.txt', $output.$new_cron);
exec('crontab /tmp/crontab.txt');

// Remove cron
$cronjob = "30 * * * * cd /home/account/public_html/; /usr/local/bin/php -f controller.php ".$argument1.PHP_EOL;
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');  // pull current cron jobs
if (strstr($output, $cronjob)) // found
   {
   $newcron = str_replace($cronjob,"",$output);  // delete it
   file_put_contents('../tmp/crontab.txt', $newcron.PHP_EOL);  // Save
   exec('crontab ../tmp/crontab.txt'); // Send back
   }
?>
```

Under Plesk I have scheduled tasks. How do I use PHP to create and remove those? Or is there another method?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule task at Home > Subscriptions > example.tld > Scheduled Tasks:

[image: Plesk 12.5 cron job scheduling tasks]

Since **Plesk 12.5** there are options of task type:

[image: Plesk 12.5 cron job scheduling tasks]